# dynamic html forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic

I am working on dynamic form. 
i have a radio button, if a user select a radio button, i want to populate a drop down menu based on the radio button values.

eg. if radio button value=value1 show drop menu of  3 items (apple, banana, mango)

eg. if radio button value=value2 show drop menu of  5 items (apple, banana, mango,apricot, ornage)

etc. I have used css to hide and show the drop down menu.

(1) the problem i am having is, this doesn't work when i insert my form in a `<table></table>`; when i remove the table tags it works. its a bit strange...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function changeDiv(the_div,the_change)
{
  var the_style = getStyleObject(the_div);
  if (the_style != false)
  {
    the_style.display = the_change;
  }
}

function hideAll()
{
  changeDiv("main_category","none");
  changeDiv("another_category","none");
  changeDiv("other_category","none");
}

function getStyleObject(objectId) {
  if (document.getElementById && document.getElementById(objectId)) {
    return document.getElementById(objectId).style;
  } else if (document.all && document.all(objectId)) {
    return document.all(objectId).style;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>

<tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top">Main Category:</td>
  <td>
  <input type="radio" name="main_cat" onClick="hideAll(); changeDiv('main_category','block');" value="value1">value1<br />
  <input type="radio" name="main_cat" onClick="hideAll(); changeDiv('main_category','block');" value="value2">value2<br />
  <input type="radio" name="main_cat" onClick="hideAll(); changeDiv('main_category','block');" value="value3">value3<br />
  <input type="radio" name="main_cat" onClick="hideAll(); changeDiv('main_category','block');" value="value4">value4
  </td>
</tr>


<div id="main_category" style="margin-left:30px;display:none">
<tr>
  <td align="right">Options:</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</div>

<tr>
  <td align="right">Aanother Category:</td>
  <td>
  <input type="radio" name="another_cat" onClick="hideAll(); changeDiv('another_category','block');" value="Yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="another_cat" value="No">No
  </td>
</tr>


<div id="another_category" style="margin-left:30px;display:none;">
<tr>
  <td align="right">Other Category:</td>
  <td>

  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align="right">Interest:</td>
  <td>

  </td>
</tr>
</div>





</table>
</body>
</html>
```

(2) second question is, i have a second radio buttons like this:
eg. if radio button value=value1 show drop menu of  3 items (apple, banana, mango)
eg. if radio button value=value2 show drop menu of  5 items (apple, banana, mango,apricot, ornage) etc. I have used css to hide and show the drop down menu.

now the trick is, if i already selected value=value1, i don't want to show value1 again in the second radio button

any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i inserted a code here but it doesnt show, what is the syntax for inserting a code?

Comment: Use at least four spaces before any text in each line of your code area, and make sure there's an empty line before and after your code block. StackOverflow will take care of the rest.

Comment: To easily insert code, you can just paste it in, select it, and then press the `101010` button, which will automatically indent it 4 spaces as StriplingWarrior suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                     var comList= new Array("apple","banana","mango");
                     var list = new Array("orage", "apricot");
                     var val1selected = 0;  

             function loadDropDown(option){
                         setSelectdVal(option)
                         createDropDown(option)
                     }  
                 function setSelectdVal(option){
                         if (option == 1){
                           val1selected = 1; 
                         } 
                     }       

                     function createDropDown(option){
                        html = "";
                        html = html + '<select id="id">'
                        var arr = getArray(option);
                        for (var i=arr.length-1; i>=0; --i ){
                            html = html + '<option value="' + i + '">' + arr[i] + '</option>' 
                        }
                        html = html + '</select>'
                        document.getElementById('selectTag').innerHTML = html;
             }
                     function getArray(option){
                        var a = comList;
                        if ((option == 2) && (val1selected == 0)){
                           a = comList.concat(list)
                        }
                        return a;
                     }

                </script>
    </head>
        <body>
        <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="options" onClick=loadDropDown(1);>value1</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="options" onClick=loadDropDown(2);>value2</td>
                    </tr>
            <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td id="selectTag"></td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>
        </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at some Javascript frameworks which will make your life a lot easier. Take a look at ExtJS: http://www.sencha.com/products/js/ or jQuery: http://jquery.com/ these frameworks can handle your problems with ease.

Comment: thanks, i actually i have a code that i added with my post but somehow its not showing.